# How to get multiple values of a record with map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I can have multiple accounts and accounts can have multiple emails. I have a method that counts all the unique email from every account, but that is not what I want however.

Instead I want to return all the unique email from just one account NOT all, as the method is currently doing.

Here is my current method:

```
 class AccountEmails
  def self.count
    accounts = Account.all

    alert = accounts.map do |a|
      a.users.first.alert_email.split(",")
    end

    billing = accounts.map do |a|
      a.users.first.billing_email.split(",")
    end

    user = accounts.map do |a|
      a.users.first.email.split(",")
    end

    snitch = accounts.map do |a|
      a.snitches.map { |s| s.alert_email.split(",") }
    end

    [alert, billing, user, snitch].flatten.uniq.count
  end
end
```

This will return all the email that are unique from all the accounts. I want to return all the unique email for each account, so account 1 could have four unique email and account 2 could have five unique email.

Comment: use group by http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#total-of-grouped-items

Comment: (1) What does the data look like in the database? Table schema, relations, ... (2) Are you really storing comma-delimited lists of email addresses in a single field? If you are, your first step is to stop doing that, that sort of anti-pattern will just make your life miserable.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimal input data and your expected output. Without that we have to reverse engineer the data then guess whether the output is correct, which wastes our time.

Comment: This is sort of a strange example you've given us. Is this a standalone example or is it a part of a larger application? Is AccountEmails a joins table? Are you using ActiveRecord or some other kind of ORM? If you were, this problem would be as easy to solve as typing `account.emails.uniq  `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying you want a single method that gives you all the unique emails for **each** account. If I'm understanding you, I would do something like this:

```
class Account
  def all_emails
    # I'm assuming here that you actually only want the unique
    # emails on the first user for each account
    user = self.users.first
    [
      user.alert_email.split(","),
      user.billing_email.split(","),
      user.email.split(","),
      self.snitches.map{|snitch| snitch.alert_email.split(",") }
    ].flatten
  end

  def unique_emails
    all_emails.uniq
  end
end

class AccountEmails
  def self.unique
    Account.all.includes(:snitches).map do |account|
      account.uniq_emails
    end
  end

  def self.count
    uniq.flatten.count
  end
end
```

Comment: Eager loading `users` might be a mistake here if there's a lot of users for some accounts. Only the first seems to be necessary.

Comment: Fair enough - I removed the eager loading. I guess I wasn't imagining many users in an account but there could certainly be cases for that.

Comment: I always assume there's going to be a billion of any particular association so as to not load *everything* out of laziness or convenience. Sometimes the truth is a lot closer to a billion than you realize. This looks pretty good in its current form, it should perform alright under most circumstances.